# How to prevent display of iPhone app from App Store, if the device using latest version

Tags: ios, app-store

I have my old application in the App Store that supports older versions of iOS. 
Recently I have created a new application, which supports only iOS version 6.0 plus onwards. And I uploaded in the App Store as well. Now if any user using with iOS 6.0 + version devices, they are getting the old as well as the new application. How to prevent the display of old application in new version devices?

Comment: You can't do that, and it's not really a programming question, so Apple developer forums might be a better place to ask questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible, you can't prevent Apps to be displayed for specific devices/ios-versions.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible to do.Then ?

If the new app is an **updated version** of your old app, You would have used the same **bundle identifier** and submit the new app as an **update to the previous app**. The targeted ios version is not a problem, because the new update will shown only to the users who are using iOS 6.0 +